# How can I solve Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found error on php

Tags: php, xampp, intl

I am trying to use IntlDateFormatter class to format the local time but it is giving error as `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "IntlDateFormatter" not found`. I tried to solve it by uncommenting the extension=intl in php.ini. So it did not work. My PHP version is 8.1.6. Here is the code:

```
    <?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
$currentDay = date('D');   //$d = date(‘D’);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Madrid', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$data1 = $formatter->format(time());



if(date('D') === 'Wed' && date('G') >= 14 && date('G') < 24){
    $content = "<h2><b>Estrazioni del Lotto e del Superenalotto di oggi ".$data1." in diretta: chi vincerà</b></h2>";
    echo $content;
}
    $data = array(
        //'post_content' => $leadContent,
    );
?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

Comment: Thanks but in windows there is just one way to manually install. It is uncommenting of the extension in php.ini. I did it but its not working.

Comment: Sometimes there are 2 `php.ini` files, one for the PHP CLI and one for the WebServer version of PHP. Did you update the correct one?

Comment: Of course you can always check by running a script like `<?php phpinfo(); ?> and making sure INTL is actually registered

Comment: @RiggsFolly I checked it. There is nothing like INTL.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes I updated the correct one.

Comment: Then you didnt activate the extension. Check the first panel of info in the `phpinfo()` output for a row with the title of ___Loaded Configuration File___ What does that say

Comment: All gone a bit quiet

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just uninstalled PHP and trying to install it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you uncommented `extension=php_intl.dll` in your `php.ini` and it didn't work you can copy `icu****.dll` files (about five of them) from PHP folder to Apache `/bin` folder then restart Apache and try again.